# QT connection to database: Error

Tags: qt

I'm trying to connect to MAMP Database with QT in C++ but it does not work

```
QString message = ui->lineEdit->text();
QSqlDatabase db;
db.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
db.setPort(8889);
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("root");
db.setDatabaseName("base");
db.open();
if(!db.isOpen()) {
    qDebug() << "error";
}
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.prepare("INSERT INTO messages VALUES id, " + message);
query.exec();
db.close();
```

> error QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open

Why?

It is not logic because MAMP is running and its database too.

Comment: MAMP is a MySQL database server, you should use MySQL driver (e.g. `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");`) after installing MySQL client libraries on your system.

Comment: After changing, I have QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded. how to install QMySQL Drivers ?